# Convert Key Value to matrix in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I using twig to render data, to html. Data I got from server is a key-value. for example :

```
| Key | Value |
|-----|-------|
| A   | 1     |
| A   | 2     |
| B   |       |
| C   | 10    |
```

I need to render this data to table like this :

```
| A | B | C  |
|---|---|----|
| 1 | 0 | 10 |
| 2 | 0 | 0  |
```

this is what i've tried :

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        {% set now = '' %}
        {% set arrKey = [] %}
        {% for data in datas %}
            {% if now != data.key %}
                <th>{{ data.key }}</th>
                {% set now = data.key %}
            {% else %}
                {% set arrKey = arrKey|merge([now]) %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% set rowNow = '' %}
    {% for key in arrKey %}
        <tr>
            {% for data in datas %}
                {% if rowNow != dataKey %}
                    {% if data.value is empty %}
                        <td>0</td>
                    {% else %}
                        <td>{{ data.value }}</td>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% set rowNow = data.key %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

but this still wrong, it will render :

```
| A | B | C  |
|---|---|----|
| 1 | 0 | 10 |
| 1 | 0 | 10 |
```

please help me how to solve this?

Comment: It seems to me your data structure needs a little bit rearrangement before being displayed, this means before you pass it to twig. Do you insist on using a `<table>` to display the data?

Comment: Yes, because it really need render in table

Comment: I specifically meant the `<table>` tag, I mean what if you can display them using `<div>` tags while they still look like a table? Of course if you want too keep the `<table>` tag there are still solutions available for you.

Comment: no problem in div, :) thanks if you can help me, because my client need to see it in table-like, as long as it feels like table, no problem dude

Comment: My suggestion is you change the structure of the data (before trying to render it) in a way that all values for a specific key be grouped together. For example a `$data` array with keys `A,B,C` and for each key you have an array including all values for that key so we have `$data['A'] = [1,2]`, `$data['B'] = []`, `$data['C'] = [10]`. Can you do this with your data?

Comment: @Nima means u need to convert your data before passing it to `twig`

Comment: I using symfony PHP, I dont know how to convert it in PHP either, if it the best way, can you help me show how to do that?

Comment: I will try, but you need to add the piece of PHP code that is responsible for building this `data` array to your question. And I should mention, it is possible to do it in the Twig template file, but I really don't recommend it because to me the logic behind it is not strictly related to the representation.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and create a dedicated *view model*, which fits the requirements of that view and that you construct via the original *model*. This way you could maybe even reuse it in other parts of your application. Don't do heavy stuff in the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to manage this is to convert the data inside the controller. This is because the `merge` filter is a pain to work with. Anyway if you wanted to do it in pure `twig`, here is how

```
{% set data = [
    { 'key': 'A', 'value': 1, },
    { 'key': 'A', 'value': 2, },
    { 'key': 'B', 'value': null, },
    { 'key': 'C', 'value': 2, },
    { 'key': 'C', 'value': 4, },
    { 'key': 'A', 'value': 3, },
    { 'key': 'A', 'value': 4, },
] %}


{% set temp  = [] %}
{% for row in data %}
    {% if not (row.key in temp|keys) %}
        {% set temp = temp | merge({ (row.key) : [] }) %}
    {% endif %}

    {% set temp = temp | merge({(row.key):(temp[row.key]|merge([ row.value, ]))}) %}
{% endfor %}

{% set max = 0 %}
{% for data in temp %}{% if data|length > max %}{% set max = data|length %}{% endif %}{% endfor %}

<table>
    <tr>
    {% for key in temp|keys %}
        <th>{{ key }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% for i in 0..(max-1) %}
    <tr>
        {% for data in temp %}
        <td>{{ data[i] | default(0) }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/ogxse9)